Row level security with multiple columns in Power BI
In order to be able to give access level to each user, I did the following.
I have a main database in which there are columns such as buyer and seller, transaction volume, transaction value,...

Now I want each users to see specific buyers.
For this, I created a database with two columns of User and Buyer name
And I connected these two databases with the buyer column and wrote the condition inside the role and it works.

[user]=USERNAME()
The problem is, my manager asked me to add a new condition, that every user can see customers who are either buyers  or sellers.
It means that two columns are required.
Considering that my two tables are connected with the buyer, I don't know how to solve this problem.
Actually, I want user 1 to see all the lines where the buyer or seller is A, B. (command condition on two columns)
And I need to say that the unique values ​​of the buyer and seller columns are the same. (We have a total of 112 customers who can be both buyers and sellers)

You didn't share your model so I am assuming that you have 2 tables one for user access and transactions liked through the buyer.
You can create a CC table where you have all the possible buyer and seller combinations for each user :
UserBuyerSellerAccess =
UNION (
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        UserAccess,
        "User", UserAccess[User],
        "Customer", UserAccess[Buyer]
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        Transactions,
        "User", UserAccess[User],
        "Customer", Transactions[Seller]
    )
)

Then you can then modify the filter condition for the role definition :
[User] = USERNAME() && (
    RELATED(UserBuyerSellerAccess[Customer]) = Transactions[Buyer] ||
    RELATED(UserBuyerSellerAccess[Customer]) = Transactions[Seller]
)


thanks for answer but  But this is not true.
Let me explain better. My user database has only two columns, userName and people's name (who can be buyers or sellers).
In the main database, I have two columns, one buyer and one seller.
Now I don't know how to connect these two tables. (The first problem)
Second, how to write a condition so that any user can see data , whether he is a buyer or a seller.

That is why I asked for sample data and the model
